# Checking an array of objects to see if each object shares a value, then do something (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am making a basic lift simulator. I have a `Building` object which contains an array of `Person` objects and each one of these `Person` objects has a `boolean` named `travelComplete`, which is initialized as `false` but is changed to `true` during the lifetime of the program.

```
class Building {

    private int floorNumber;
    public Lift[] lifts;
    public Person[] people;

    public void moveElevator() { }

    public void loadPeople() { }

    public void unloadPeople() { }
}

class Person {
    private boolean travelComplete = false;
    private int currentFloor;
    private int destFloor;
}
```

I need to have a loop in the main method that runs the elevator until every object's `travelComplete` variable in the `people` array is `true`. Possibly something along these lines:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    while (each object in people[] != true) { // This obviously wouldn't
                                              // work but is the closest I
                                              // can get.
        object.loadPeople();
        object.moveElevator();
        object.unloadPeople();
    }
}
```

Sorry if there is a similar thread, I could not find it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For clarification, the elevators will keep running until the check returns 100% of the objects as having `travelComplete == true`, at which point the simulation will end.

Comment: I assume simulation means printing to console stuff like `Loading 5 people into lift 1. Lift 1 Started. Lift 1 Arrived. Unloading 5 people from lift 1.` Can you write what the expected output should look like? (I think english word for lift is elevator btw)

Comment: It is not very clear what you are doing here. Your loop seems to iterate over an array of `Person`s but you call the methods of `Building` on (what seems to be) the current array item.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over each person and see if their travel is complete to decide whether to continue operating your elevator:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  boolean keepRunning = true;
  while (keepRunning) {
    object.loadPeople();
    object.moveElevator();
    object.unloadPeople();

    //this loop will run over each person
    //and set the flag to continue looping
    //if anyone has not finished their travel
    keepRunning = false;
    for (Person person : people) {
      if (!person.travelComplete) {
        keepRunning = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by streaming through the array and checking if any entry matches a predicate like so:

```
while (Arrays.stream(people).anyMatch(
        person -> !person.travelComplete))
{
    object.loadPeople();
    object.moveElevator();
    object.unloadPeople();
}
```

`anyMatch` will return true whenever the predicate evaluates to true for any of the arrays entries.

here is a more general example since it is not very clear what you do with `.loadPeople()`:

```
public static class Foo {
  boolean condition;
}

public static void main(String[] args) { 
  Foo foos[];
  int cnt;

  // all conditions are false    
  foos = new Foo[]{new Foo(), new Foo(), new Foo()};
  cnt  = 0;

  // while any foo has a false condition
  while (Arrays.stream(foos).anyMatch(foo -> !foo.condition)) {
    System.out.println(cnt);
    foos[cnt].condition = true;
    cnt++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a getter for the `boolean`, this should work fine, by counting the number of people who doesn't have finished their travels yet.

```
while (Arrays.asList(people).stream().filter(p -> !p.travelComplete).count() > 0) {
    // Do your thing
}
```

Comment: lupz anwsers look better than mine

Comment: You need to remove both the semicolons, otherwise your while loop has not effect!

Comment: Of course thanks for correcting my silly error and my english^^